# Ionic 4 long press to trigger reorder

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

How can I implement long press to reorder in Ionic 4? I've found an example for Ionic 1, but can't seem to get things to work for the new versions.

Comment: can you please share your code where you're attempting to do this?